# Since when is adding user to docker group not enough to execute docker client and I need `newgrp docker` every time?

Tags: docker, permissions

I used docker extensively for a couple of years now and we always just added the user to the docker group to use the client.

Recently, on a ubuntu 18.04 using a docker 18.09 I need to call newgrp docker in each shell before I get access to the docker socket!?!

Why like this? It sucks!

This is needed within a jenkins container. the easy workaround is to do a usermod -g docker jenkins inside the container. However, this was NOT necessary one year ago :(

Comment: is it the kernel version > 4.5 maybe?

Comment: Did you find a solution since then?

Answer (score 0):

> Recently, on a ubuntu 18.04 using a docker 18.09 I need to call newgrp docker in each shell before I get access to the docker socket!?!

Have you logged out and back in again, since adding yourself to the `docker` group?

> This is needed within a jenkins container. the easy workaround is to do a usermod -g docker jenkins inside the container. However, this was NOT necessary one year ago :(

Provided you mount the Docker socket into your Jenkins container, this should not be required. Which user does Jenkins run as?

Comment: I found something about a new cgroups api in kernel since 4.5 and are wondering if that could apply. 

On the host it does indeed have to do with the top level login shell thats true.

However, I still have the same permission issue inside the jenkins container. :(